# Add multiple commands in single alias

Tags: bash, shell

I want to have only one alias for multiple commands.

For example, I want a one alias for mkdir  and cd  via single alias.

I tried to make a script which does that but it wouldn't execute the second command.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p $1
cd $1
```

The name of the script would be mkd.sh

And call above script through an alias for example,

```
alias mkd '~/mkd.sh'
```

I know this is very basic, I'm new to the Linux system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does execute the second command, but it does it in a subshell.   When it exits the subshell, it goes back to the parent shell's directory.

What you want is a function, which executes in the current shell's environment.  Try:

```
mkd() { mkdir -p $1 && cd $1; }
```

Aliases cannot take parameters, so they're not useful for what you want.  You would call the above with something like `mkd newdir`.  If you define this in your `.bashrc`, and it will work for all new sessions afterwards.

Comment: I dont want to use two different shrc. Is it possible to do the same in .cshrc?

Comment: no not possible. `csh` VS almost all other `sh` implementations are completely different. If you're still using `csh` because of `!!` etc. it is possible to turn on such features in other `sh`ells. As I commented here recently, there was a discussion in comp.unix.shell about 15-20 years ago how to write cross-shell compatible `.rc` files, but they are just not worth the trouble, you are very limited in what you can do, and you're creating a maintenance nightmare, quite possibly for yourself. Rethink you approach to your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .bashrc

```sh
runMKD() {
mkdir -p $1;
cd $1;
}
alias mkd=runMKD
```

Comment: show us output from `echo SHELL=$SHELL` . Good luck.

Comment: SHELL=/bin/tcsh

Comment: @JigarVaidya -- if your shell is `/bin/tcsh` why is the question tagged `bash`?

Comment: `tcsh` doesn't support functions. Good luck.